# How to use Java regex or Java streams for the given string pattern and create a map out of it

Tags: java, regex, java-8, java-stream

I have a string with the following pattern,

```
String test = "name=ravi,age=30,id=1;name=teja,age=32,id=2";
```

As you can see above, ";" is used to separate persons and "," is used to separate person's attributes and "=" to map the values of those attributes.

I would like to convert the above string into a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` where the key for the outer map is the id and the key for the inner map is the name.

Given that it is always guaranteed to have unique ids and names across the string, how do I achieve the requirement using Java regex or Java streams?

I could have done this using StringTokenizer or "split" method, but I would like to see if there is any other better way of doing this.

Edit: I have reached this far till now

```
List<String> persons =
                Arrays.asList(test.split(";"));

        List<List<String>> personAttribs =
                persons.stream().map(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(","))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am unable to take the  personAttribs and convert that to the map I am looking for.

Comment: You can do it using `split` method easily.

Comment: @Azhy, yes I could use `split`, but I would like to see if there is a way to do it using the regex patterns or java streams

Comment: There are endless different ways to do what you want using regex or streams.  What have you already tried?  Can you show any code you've already tried? Can you show a regex you tried that isn't working?  Can you show any functions you wrote to stream through that aren't working?

Comment: @geneSummons, edited the question with the piece of code I tried. Please take a look

Comment: what happens with the `age=30`? is that also put into a map?

Comment: @Lino - yes. The `age` parameter would go as a value in the inner map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely just for fun:

```
    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(",");
    Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("=");
    String[] tokens = test.split(";");

    for (String token : tokens) {
        List<String> list = p2.splitAsStream(token)
                .flatMap(x -> p3.splitAsStream(x))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        result.put(list.get(5), IntStream.of(0, 2)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(list::get, x -> list.get(x + 1))));
    }

    System.out.println(result); // {1={name=ravi, age=30}, 2={name=teja, age=32}}
```

With `java-9` this could be even nicer:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(";");
    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(",");
    Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("=");

    List<String> list = p.splitAsStream(test)
            .flatMap(p2::splitAsStream)
            .flatMap(p3::splitAsStream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = IntStream.iterate(5, x -> x + 6)
            .limit(list.size() / 6)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    list::get,
                    x -> Map.of(
                          list.get(x - 5), 
                          list.get(x - 4), 
                          list.get(x - 3), 
                          list.get(x - 2))));
```

Comment: sorry I was away for a few days. Can you please help me understand why you were using `list.get(5)`, `IntStream.of(0,2).boxed()`? I am finding it hard to understand as I'm relatively new to Java streams

Comment: @Ravi think about your input (a single token) `name=ravi,age=30,id=1`, what I do is basically transform it to a List `name, ravi, age, 30, id, 1`. `Now, list.get(5)` in such ca case will be `1` - this is the ID you are interested in. This is the value in your `Map`. Now think about your `innerMap` as the `Value`... You said you care about `name` and `age`. In that initial `List`, `name` is on position zero and it's value is on position `1`; thus `IntStream.of(0,2)` goes and takes zero index value from that List and uses it as a Key in the inner Map (`name`), same for the value...

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation @Eugene. Much helpful